# CSS div border around child divs

Tags: css, html

1. I have one container div, which contains 3 divs inside it.
2. When i write border:1px solid red for container div, border is shown only on top of these 3 child divs, but not around them.
3. Below is css code.

   ```
   #cont {
       width:800px;
       margin-right:auto;
       margin-left:auto; 
       border:1px dashed red;
       padding:2px;
   }
   #third, #second, #first {
       width:260px;
       float:left;
       margin:2px;
   }
   ```

Html code:

```
![<div id="cont">
<div id="third"><p>A demo text </p></br>
<p>A demo text </p></br>
<p>A demo text </p></br>
<p>A demo text </p></br>
</div>

<div id="second"><p>A demo text </p></br>
<p>A demo text </p></br>
<p>A demo text </p></br>
<p>A demo text </p></br>
</div>

<div id="third"><p>A demo text </p></br>
<p>A demo text </p></br>
<p>A demo text </p></br>
<p>A demo text </p></br>
</div>
</div>][1]
```

Comment: add below the third div: `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` that most likely will do the trick

Comment: tried clear: right / left /both . . but no success. .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add overflow:hidden;

```
#cont {width:800px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto; border:1px dashed red;padding:2px; overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: thanks! it worked, could you explain a bit...because what i know about overflow doesn't explains me how this happens. (overflow: controls data which may overflow, from an element) so what caused overflow here?

Comment: This is rule, because child elements used floating, so must to remove floating. In this equivalent to `clearfix`.  `.clearfix{*zoom:1}.clearfix:after{content:".";height:0;visibility:hidden;display:block;clear:both}` `<div id="cont" class="clearfix">`

Answer (score 0):

`<div style="clear:both;float:none;"></div>` well solve your problem. added it under the div's

Comment: um . .yes it did. . .thanks for info. . but i need to float my child div to left. (oops my requirement ; 3 column layout)

Comment: you need to place the code that I gave you, before the last div in your code.

Answer (score 0):

add overflow:hidden to the #cont element

Comment: how come i could not see, your answer first, as you replied before @jrkey . . . they say IE6 sucks, they say right. (i could see your post rendered properly in firefox) thanks