# Draw border boxes around any CSS Grid items on a page

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am working on a site that uses CSS Grids. Sometimes debugging them can be a little tricky. I know most browsers allow you to inspect the code to identify problems, but I would like to simply highlight the grid lines as it is much easier to debug visually than with the inspector up.

I currently use code that looks like this:

```
.grid-container * {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.grid-container *:after {
  content:attr(class);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
```

The code draws a red border around the grid container and also displays the class name of the grid. That works great, but unfortunately, it also does the same thing for anything contained within the grid, like text, hrefs, images, and the like.

I would like the code to *only* draw a red box around CSS Grids and display their class name. Looking on Stack Overflow, the best option I could find was the article [Border around CSS Grid item div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434529/css-div-border-around-child-divs). Unfortunately, that just hard-codes a specific grid.

Is there a method (CSS media query? JS? Something else?) to only identify *any* grid items and display them with a border and display the class name?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the **descendant** selector  . Since you only want to target children of the grid container, instead you want to use the **child** selector `>`:

```css
.grid-container>* { }
.grid-container>*::after {}
```

Comment: I can appreciate your change for the code I’m using, but I don’t think it addresses my need to see a border around all CSS grids. Is that correct?